# regular expressions with dplyr pivot wide to long,

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, pivot-table, tidyr

I have a database of connection pipes with the inflow (letters) and outflow as numbers.

```
df=data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5), A-Y=c(0,1,0,1,0), B-Z=c(1,1,1,0,0), C-W=c(1,1,0,0,0))
df
df
  id A.Y B.Z C.W
1  1   0   1   1
2  2   1   1   1
3  3   0   1   0
4  4   1   0   0
5  5   0   0   0
```

i want to convert it to long format as follows

```
df.out<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5), inflow=c("B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "B", "A",""), outflow=c("Z", "W", "Y", "Z", "W", "Z","Y",""))
 df.out
  id inflow outflow
  1      B       Z
  1      C       W
  2      A       Y
  2      B       Z
  2      C       W
  3      B       Z
  4      A       Y
  5
```

I think I should use `pivot_longer` but I am not sure how to define the split.

```
df %>% pivot_longer(cols=A.Y:C.W, names_to=c("Inflow", "Outflow"), names_pattern = ".-.", values_to = status)

Error: `regex` should define 2 groups;  found.
```

does not seem to work

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `names_sep`.

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(df, cols = -id, 
                    names_to = c('inflow', 'outflow'), 
                    names_sep = '\\.') %>%
  filter(value == 1) %>%
  select(-value)

#     id inflow outflow
#  <dbl> <chr>  <chr>  
#1     1 B      Z      
#2     1 C      W      
#3     2 A      Y      
#4     2 B      Z      
#5     2 C      W      
#6     3 B      Z      
#7     4 A      Y
```

**data**

```
df=data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5), A.Y=c(0,1,0,1,0), 
              B.Z=c(1,1,1,0,0), C.W=c(1,1,0,0,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide capture groups:

```
df <- tibble(
  id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  A_Y = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0),
  B_Z = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0),
  C_W = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
)
df

df %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -id,
    names_to = c("Inflow", "Outflow"),
    names_pattern = "(.)_(.)",
    values_to = "status"
  ) %>%
  filter(status == 1) %>%
  select(-status)
```

Edit:
In answer to comment - Currently the regex `"(.)_(.)"` is looking for any single character `(.)` followed by an underscore and then another single character. To make it more specific replace the `.` with another regex e.g. `([A-Z])_([A-Z])` would only find uppercase A-Z (so would still work on the example). For a longer word something like `(.+)_(.+)` where `+` implies one or more. Try to make the regex as specific as you can, provided it's still readable!

@Ronak suggested `names_sep = '\\.'` instead of `names_pattern` which is a simpler solution provided the seperator is consistent (`names_sep = "_"` to fit with my example!)

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work. If instead I have the pattern "word_word" how should I modify the code?